# SOLR Query for customized Sort in the Filtered result?

Tags: sorting, solr, filter

In the Solr indexed records, lets say i have this sample records (e.g. JSON):

```
{
    "title":"Innovation Life and Strategy",
    "author":"Sarah Howard",
},
{
    "title":"Simple Life", <--- This will be ignored
    "author":"W. David",
},
{
    "title":"Today's Innovations",
    "author":"Michael Wayne", <--- This Author will be listed at the top
},
{
    "title":"The Innovation Records",
    "author":"Tommy Wright",
},
etc ..
```

How to make a Solr Query to:

- Filtered by `innovation` in the `title` fields
  (So we got 3 records there)
- Then, **sort the result** by placing the **author: `Wayne` at the top**

So the final result should be:

```
{
    "title":"Today's Innovations",
    "author":"Michael Wayne",
},
{
    "title":"Innovation Life and Strategy",
    "author":"Sarah Howard",
},
{
    "title":"The Innovation Records",
    "author":"Tommy Chen",
},
```

I only get to the first step, `fq=title:*Innovation*`
But i don't know the query for second step (custom sorting).
How can i get it please?

Comment: Whats the basis or logic or rule for the Custom sorting ?? Is there any fixed logic ???

Comment: I meant whats the logic behind your custom sorting ? As the focus seems wayne in this case but would be different in others. You can boost your results for wayne which will cause it to come up always. However, without any ruleset this would not make sense and its not generic.

Comment: Boost? You mean we can set the display order priority by using Boost? Could you give some sample about that?

Comment: If you are using dismax query handler you can easily boost records like bq=author:wayne^1.5. This will boost records with author having wayne. However, this is too specific and not generic rule.

Answer (score 4):

You could use field boosting instead of sorting. Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ for details.

You probably need something like:

```
q=title:*&bq=author:Wayne^10&fq=title:*Innovation*
```

This yields all documents having "Innovation" in the title, scoring those matching "Wayne"   higher.

Make sure "author" is indexed using WhitespaceTokenizer (as opposed to KeywordTokenizer), or you will not be able to search using separated words (see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, i don't think it's possible, because author is an multi-valued-field, because there are 2 values: first name and surname.
So if you like to order by surname, you have to split this field into 2 fields:
author_first_name, author_surname

You could split the name on indexing time, for example by using the data import handler.

An other solution would be writing an own sorting algorithm in java.

The point (in every case) is to find, what the surename is, because not every name consists of only 2 names, like `Docotor Tommy Chen` or `kim jong il` - there are also exists surnames consists of 2 names (especially in Asia).

This is the real problem, i think.

Comment: Hmmm.. At least, so how would you sort for the Single Valued Fields, after Filtered?

Comment: fq=title:*Innovation*&sort=author desc   take a look at this:  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

Comment: No, there is no placement sorting about to put `wayne` at the top. Just the simple A~Z order.

Comment: by the way, if i look at your examples, fq=title:*Innovation* will return the same results like fq=title:Innovation if stemming is active

Comment: solr takes the author as one string. so it dos not know "wayne", but it know "Michael Wayne". Using my example you are using descending sorting, which means, the "highest" letter first...depending on the first character of the author name. In this Case "M". But looking at your example "M" is the "smallest" character. This example will crate the following order: "Tommy Chen" -> "Sarah Howard" ->  "Michael Wayne" ... depending on the descending alphabetical order (of the first character) T->S->M. you can use `&sort=author asc`to change the order

Comment: I don't think this is the reliable solution. You are just grounding on this 3 Sample Records. How about putting "Robert" at the top of .. "Amy", "Kevin", "Steven", "Ted" ?